# Kendo UI: Grid with custom edit template, DatePicker won't bind when using API to set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-grid

Here is my JSBin.  Essentially, when programmatically setting the value of a Kendo DatePicker within a custom popup editor template, the value does not unbind back to the data source.  Do I need to be calling additional methods to ensure the value unbinds when setting it in this way?

[My JSBin](http://jsbin.com/haxabihe/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to trigger the Kendo UI change event per the below.

```
function setDate(e)
          {
            var datePicker = $("#DateCreated").data("kendoDatePicker");           
            datePicker.value(new Date());
            datePicker.trigger("change");
          }
```